# How to make Windows 10 notifications appear in the top right of the desktop?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

Is it possible to configure Windows 10 notifications to appear in the top right of the desktop? How?

Comment: You would need to move the taskbar to the top of your screen to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can do it with some registry modifications. Here's the step to follow:

1. Open the Registry Editor (with the command `regedit`)
2. Go to following key: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
3. Create a new DWORD(32bits) Value called `DisplayToastAtBottom` and enter 0 as Value data
4. Restart your computer

Comment: Toast is already at bottom, we want it at top?

Comment: @Eoin that's what the `0` value is for (`0` being _false_). Note, I don't think this solution works with more recent Windows 10 builds unfortunately 

Comment: This option only worked in very early builds of Windows 10 and was removed before the final release of Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it can't be done:

> We realize the inconvenience you are experiencing with not able to move the position of Toast notification from bottom to top. We will certainly help you.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/how-to-change-toast-notifications-position/98d3efba-dd78-4a53-b4b4-9ba36b28c794

Answer (score 2):

It actually *can* be done!

I made a program that will put notifications at the top of the screen:
https://github.com/SamarthCat/notifications-at-top

The way it works is by finding the window handle of the notification and changing the window's position with the windows API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like there isn't a way to change the position of the Toast notification.

Alternatively, you may want to change the location of your taskbar if constant pop-up notifications are getting in your way of accessing the system tray.

Simply do this by:

1. Right-clicking on the taskbar
2. Untick lock taskbar
3. Drag the taskbar to any edge of your screen of your choosing, preferably on the left
4. Relock your taskbar

Comment: It's not just the system tray it's EVERYTHING.  The only thing top right blocks is closing things down which is not a regular task.

Comment: This doesn't change the location of notifications...