# Windows 10 displays notifications in the wrong place

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop screen with 2560x1440 resolution and a monitor with 1920x1200.

It's set up like this:

[image]

Notifications display in such a way the actual contents are not visible. Maybe it's set up to display in the lower right corner of an 1440 high display. How do I fix this? Restarting Windows Explorer, rebooting doesn't help. Even if I move it with https://superuser.com/a/1715024/41259 the window is cut off so it doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This caused by different scaling. Set your primary and secondary displays to the same scaling, possibly reboot and it's working. You can test using the example from https://github.com/GitHub30/toast-notification-examples/blob/main/README.md

```
$bodyText = 'A single string wrapped across a maximum of three lines of text.'

$ToastText01 = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::ToastText01
$TemplateContent = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::GetTemplateContent($ToastText01)
$TemplateContent.SelectSingleNode('//text[@id="1"]').InnerText = $bodyText
$AppId = '{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($AppId).Show($TemplateContent)
```